# How to get context variables from the response of IBM watson assistant V2 using Nodejs?

Tags: node.js, ibm-cloud, chatbot, ibm-watson, watson-assistant

We are using IBM watson assistant for NLU and backend we are using Nodejs for API calling. I am able to connect and get JSON response from watson assistant. For that I used following package 'watson-developer-cloud/assistant/v2'.

I am handling context/slots within watson so I just want to get the values of those context variables/slots in the JSON response.

I tried to send the context variables in text response (JSON file) from watson.

Also tried to get context with watson assistant V1 but there the problem is session handling so I preferred to go with watson assistant V2

```
const AssistantV2 = require('watson-developer-cloud/assistant/v2');
const assistant = new AssistantV2({
  version: 'XXXX-XX-XX',
  iam_apikey: 'XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX',
  url: 'XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX'
});

var sess_id;

assistant.createSession({
    assistant_id: 'XXXXXXXX-XXXX-XXXX-XXXX-XXXXXXXXXXXX'
})
  .then(res => {
    sess_id=res.session_id;
})
  .catch(err => {
    console.log(err);
});

assistant.message({
    assistant_id: 'XXXXXXXX-XXXX-XXXX-XXXX-XXXXXXXXXXXX',
    session_id: sess_id,
    input: {
        'message_type': 'text',
        'text': 'Message'},
    })
    .then(res => {
        console.log(JSON.stringify(res, null, 2))
        console.log(res)})
```

Expected: 
I should get context in watson Json response

Actual:
I am not getting context in watson Json response

Comment: Can you please show us the response, and preferably, an example of the expected response?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See the [V2 API documentation for IBM Watson Assistant](https://cloud.ibm.com/apidocs/assistant-v2#send-user-input-to-assistant) and [line 473 in the Node.js SDK](https://github.com/watson-developer-cloud/node-sdk/blob/master/assistant/v2.ts#L473):

There is an input parameter **return_context**. It is **false** by default. If set to **true** it tells the server to return the context data with the message response.

```
  /** Whether to return session context with the response. If you specify `true`, the response will include the `context` property. */
    return_context?: boolean;
```

Comment: Awesome that's great!! Your advise helped me alot. Thankyou very much henrik.

Answer (score 1):

As @data_henrik rightly mentioned, you need to pass `return_context` as part of your request to see `MessageContext` in the response.

Here's a sample request with context returned from the previous response being passed

```
const AssistantV2 = require('watson-developer-cloud/assistant/v2');

const service = new AssistantV2({
  iam_apikey: '{apikey}',
  version: '2019-02-28',
  url: '{url}'
});

service.message({
  assistant_id: '{assistant_id}',
  session_id: '{session_id}',
  input: {
    'message_type': 'text',
    'text': 'Hello',
    'options': {
      'return_context': true
    }
  },
  context: {
    'global': {
      'system': {
        'user_id': 'my_user_id'
      }
    },
    'skills': {
      'main skill': {
        'user_defined': {
          'account_number': '123456'
        }
      }
    }
  }
})
  .then(res => {
    console.log(JSON.stringify(res, null, 2));
  })
  .catch(err => {
    console.log(err);
  });
```

Under `input`, you can see the `return_context` set to **true**